Question about the proof of Theorem 5 in the subsection 5.6.2 of Evans' PDE book (page 283 in the 2nd version)
This is the Theorem 5 in the subsection 5.6.2 of Evans' PDE book (second edition):
Picture 1: page 283 of Evans' book
Picture 2: page 284 of Evans' book
It's a theorem related to Morrey's inequality (Theorem 4 in the subsection 5.6.2 of the same book). I have a question about what he says after equations (27) and (28).
If the sequence of functions $ (u_m)\subset C^1(\mathbb{R}^n) $ converges to $ \overline{u} $ in $ W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ and to $ u^\ast $ in $ C^{0,1-\frac{n}{p}}(\mathbb{R}^n) $, why can we conclude that $ \overline{u}=u^\ast $ a.e. in $ U $? I haven't found any results can allow me to obtain this conclusion.

(Since we want to prove a.e. equality in $U$ and $\bar u = u$ in $U$, I will just replace $\bar u$ with $u$ in the following)
Here is a way to see it : first, note that since $U$ is a bounded set, we have $u^*\in L^p(U)$. Indeed, $u^*$ is Hölder continuous on $\mathbb R^n$, and in particular it is continuous on $\bar U$. If we denote $\|u^*\|_{C(\bar U)}$ its supremum norm on $\bar U$, we have
$$\|u^*\|_{L^p(U)}^p :=\int_{U} u^p\ dx \le \lambda(U)\cdot\|u^*\|_{C(\bar U)}^p <\infty, \tag1$$
where $\lambda(U)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $U$.
Now, obviously $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$ implies $u\in L^{p}(U)$, and so the quantity $\|u - u^*\|_{L^{p}(U)}$ is well defined. Furthermore, for all $m\ge 1$ we have :
$$\begin{align}\| u - u^*\|_{L^{p}(U)} &= \| u - u_m + u_m - u^*\|_{L^{p}(U)}\\
&\le \|u - u_m\|_{L^{p}(U)} + \|u^*- u_m\|_{L^{p}(U)}\\
&\le  \|u - u_m\|_{W^{1,p}(U)} + \lambda(U)^{1/p}\|u^* - u_m\|_{C(\bar U)}\\
&\le \|u - u_m\|_{W^{1,p}(U)} + \lambda(U)^{1/p}\|u^* - u_m\|_{C^{0,1-n/p}(\bar U)},\tag2 \end{align}  $$
where we have used inequality $(1)$ and obvious relations between respectively $L^p(U)$ and $W^{1,p}(U)$ norms, and $C(\bar U)$ and $C^{0,1-n/p}(\bar U) $ norms.
But now, since inequality $(2)$ holds for all $m$, we find by taking the limit $m\to\infty$ that
$$\|u - u^*\|_{L^{p}(U)} = 0, $$
which implies that $u$ and $u^*$ are almost everywhere equal in $U$, as we wanted.

I understand, but my question is about how to prove that $ \overline{u}=u^\ast $ a.e. without using the imbedding $$ W^{1,p}(U)\hookrightarrow C^{0,1-\frac{n}{p})(\overline{U}) $$, because I need the fact of $ \overline{u}=u^\ast $ a.e.  to prove that imbedding (see Evans' PDE book, page 284).

@jom my bad, your question mentioned Morrey's inequality so I didn't read in more detail and gave an argument using that result. Here is an alternative proof using $L^p$ norms instead.

(by the way, the $u_m$'s are defined in $\mathbb R^n$ and not in $U$ so technically this proof is not valid, but this can be easily fixed by multiplying each $u_m$ by an appropriate cutoff function. I have to go now but I can come back to add the details later if you're not convinced)
